# SQL Server - SELECT from a table when INSERT is happening at 1000 inserts/s on the same table

Tags: sql-server, concurrency

In a heavy insert environment, every insert is in a transaction scope. How can we select without dirty reads and without blocking the inserts?

Comment: enabling RCSI might be helpful , learn more about it

Comment: That's a good point. But I'm afraid I can't go ahead with that in my environment due to the existing tempdb configuration.